# Strip part of string before a particular character, in a case where the character occurs multiple times

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to strip the string off the part that occurs before the character `':'`, where `':'` may occur multiple times.
For Example:

```
input: 'Mark: I am sending the file: abc.txt'
output: 'I am sending the file: abc.txt'
```

The function I have is this (Python code)

```
def process_str(in_str):
    str_list = in_str.split(':')[1:]
    out_str = ''
    for each in str_list:
        out_str += each
    return out_str
```

The output I am getting is `'I am sending the file abc.txt'` without the second `':'`.
Is there a way to correct this? 
Also can this code be made more efficient in time and space complexity?

Comment: Could you give more examples. I'm not quite sure what your after. Why isn't `I am sending the file` striped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` isn't the best approach for this. You want to use a regular expression.

```
import re

def process_str(in_str):
  return re.sub('^.*?: ', '', in_str)
```

This returns the string without anything up to the first `:` (colon followed by space). You can read more about Python regular expressions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I thought of using regex but I'm not very proficient with it.

Answer (score 6):

How about using [**split()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

```
str = 'Mark: I am sending the file: abc.txt'
print(str.split(':', 1)[-1])
```

*Use -1 to account for list index out of bounds if the delimiter is not in the initial string*

**Output:**

```
I am sending the file: abc.txt'
```

Try it out [**here**](https://repl.it/repls/AntiquewhiteWatchfulFugu).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `out_str = ':'.join(in_str.split(':')[1:])`: since you stripped all `':'`, you need to re-insert them.

A better way would probably to use `out_str = in_str[in_str.find(':')+1:]`.
`find(':')` gives you the index of the first `':'`.

Comment: And why this was down voted? Please explain what's wrong with my answer...